# How do I bulk Insert using SubSonic?

Tags: sql, subsonic, subsonic3, bulkinsert, subsonic-active-record

I have something that looks like this

```
foreach (var user in NewUsers)
            {
                var dbUser = new User {FirstName = user.FirstName};
                dbUser.Save();
            }
```

That is too many inserts into the database.  Can I do something like?

```
User.BulkInsert(NewUsers);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Batch Query - this should solve the issue
http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/BatchQuery